# An infinite sequence of circles tangent to the unit circle and its circumscribed square

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Referring to the image, I need to find a formula for the sum of the areas of all (infinite) circles tangent to the unit circle and its circumscribed square.
[image]
Here is my approach. I focus on the first octant and I try to link two consecutive radius, let's say $R_1$ and $R_2$.
$$HO_2=CE$$
$$HO_2^{\,2}=O_1O_2^{\,2}-O_1R_1^{\,2}=(R_1+R_2)^2-(R_1-R_2)^2=4R_1R_2$$
$$CE=AB-AD-BC+DE=\tan\alpha_1-\tan\alpha_2-R_1\tan\alpha_1+R_2\tan\alpha_2$$
So, we have found that
$$((1-R_1)\tan\alpha_1-(1-R_2)\tan\alpha_2)^2=4R_1R_2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
For a generic circle of the sequence (for example the second) we can also write:
$$\frac1{\cos\alpha_2}=OD=OO_2+O_2D=1+R_2+\frac{R_2}{\cos\alpha_2}$$
Therefore,
$$\cos\alpha_2=\frac{1-R_2}{1+R_2}$$
and
$$\sin\alpha_2=\sqrt{1-\Big(\frac{1-R_2}{1+R_2}\Big)^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{R_2}}{1+R_2}$$
Finally,
$$\tan\alpha_2=\frac{2\sqrt{R_2}}{1-R_2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
Now, using the relation (2), we can rewrite the equation (1):
$$\sqrt{R_1}-\sqrt{R_2}=\sqrt{R_1R_2}$$
rewritable as
$$R_2=\frac{R_1}{(1+\sqrt{R_1})^2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(3)$$
(3) is a recurrence relation. If we compute the third term, we can notice that
$$R_3=\frac{\frac{R_1}{(1+\sqrt{R_1})^2}}{(1+\sqrt{\frac{R_1}{(1+\sqrt{R_1})^2}})^2}=\frac{R_1}{(1+2\sqrt{R_1})^2}$$
and, using induction, one can deduce the beautiful relation
$$R_{n+1}=\frac{R_1}{(1+n\sqrt{R_1})^2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(4)$$
Putting into (4) the actual value of $R_1$, we obtain (after some algebra):
$$\frac{1-R_1}{1+R_1}=\cos\alpha_1=\cos\frac\pi4=\frac{\sqrt2}2$$
$$R_1=3-2\sqrt2$$
$$R_n=\frac1{(n+\sqrt2)^2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(5)$$
Also (5) is a nice relation.
Finally, let's compute the total area $A$ ($A_n$ is the area of the n-th circle):
$$A=8\Big(\frac{A_1}2+\sum_{n=2}^\infty{A_n}\Big)$$
$$A=8\pi\Big(\frac{(3-2\sqrt2)^2}2+\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac1{(n+\sqrt2)^4}}\Big)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(6)$$
**Are my arguments correct? Does it exist a short procedure?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_theorem

Comment: Here we haven't got four mutually tangent circles, even considering the side of the square as a circle of zero curvature. The mutually tangent circles are only three.

Comment: At a given step, when you wonder what the $k$th circle is, you have the right side of the square, you have the unit circle and you have the $(k-1)$th circle. Those three are all mutually tangent, and the $k$th circle will be tangent to all three of them. You can definitely ask the theorem what its radius will be. It doesn't work for the first circle in the corner, but after that there is no issue.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Thanks a lot.